# Calendar class: set to ten days from now

Tags: java, calendar

I have the following two methods:

```
private long getTimeInMilliseconds()
    {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();


        if(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == 21)  
        {
            c.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.MONTH + 1 );
            c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        }
        else
            c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH + 10);

        if(c.get(Calendar.MONTH) > 11)
            c.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);

        return c.getTimeInMillis();
    }

public static void remainingTime(L2PcInstance player)
    {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long then = player.getExpBoostTime();

        long time = then - now;

        int hours = (int) (time / 3600000);

        player.sendMessage(hours+ " hours remaining until your EXP BOOST PERIOD ends");
    }
```

I want `getTimeInMillisSeconds()` to return the time 10 days later.  I want `remainingTime()` to show how many days (in hours) remain.

With the code above, it shows 4 days remaining and not 10.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Haven't checked the entire code, but your line c.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.MONTH + 1 ); is always being overridden by the following. Besides, you are setting the month to be the value of the constant alendar.DAY_OF_MONTH plus 1, not the current month plus 1. The latter is valid for the else part (plus 10, instead of plus 1).

Answer (score 3):

You are making a mistake in the `set()` method.

It should be

```
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + 10);
```

However, your approach is far from being the best. The one suggested in another answer (adding 10 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 milliseconds to the current time) is far better IMHO.

Comment: Thanks bro! the problem was: c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + 10);

Comment: @user1449638 If you keep this approach, you'll want to fix `c.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.MONTH + 1 )` which should be `c.set(Calendar.MONTH, c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1 );` then

Answer (score 1):

The best way to get "ten days from now" is to use timestamps/milliseconds.

You can get the current time in milliseconds from a calendar like this:

```
Calendar someCalendar = new Calendar();
long someTimestamp = someCalendar.getTimeInMillis();
```

Once you get that, you can add ten days to it (again in milliseconds):

```
long tenDays = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 10;
long tenDaysFromNow = someTimestamp + tenDays;
```

Comment: While it's true you can convert from days to milis using multiplication, I'd recommend using java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit and the methods toMilis(), toSeconds() etc -- code looks more readable that way and also you don't need to worry about your calculations. Just a suggestion.